# jquery - how to identify a form field type

Tags: jquery

I would like to know the different elements and their types in a form.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form action="save_form" method="post" id="newform" name="newform">
          <div class="form_description">
            <h2 class="editable">Form title. Click here to edit</h2>
            <p class="editable">This is your form description. Click here to edit.</p>
          </div>
          <ul id="form_body" class="ui-sortable">
          <li id="field1" class="">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="hover">
            <label class="editable" for="field1">Text1</label>
            <input type="text" name="field1" value="">
            </a>
            </li>
            <li id="field2" class="">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="hover">
            <label class="editable" for="field2">Paragraph2</label>
            <div><textarea cols="" rows="" class="textarea" name="field2"></textarea></div>
            </a>
            </li>
            <li id="radiogroup3" class="">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="hover">
            <label class="editable" for="radiogroup3">Label3</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radiogroup31" name="radiogroup3" value="1" class="element radio">
            <label class="choice editable" for="radiogroup31">option1</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radiogroup32" name="radiogroup3" value="2" class="element radio">
            <label class="choice editable" for="radiogroup32">option2</label>
            <input type="radio" id="radiogroup33" name="radiogroup3" value="3" class="element radio">
            <label class="choice editable" for="radiogroup33">option3</label>
            </a>
            </li></ul>
        </form>
```

I came up with the function below but this.type does not return any value (undefined) even though 
firebug console shows the correct value.

I cannot use attr('type') since it does not work for textarea and labels.

```
test = $('#newform').map(function(){ return $.makeArray(this.elements); });

if (test.length != 0) {
    test.each(function(){
        console.log($(this).type);
    });
}
```

Is there a way in which I can get all elements in a form, including label, textarea and radio buttons.

Comment: Do you want only `input`, `label` and `textarea` elements, or all children of the `form` element (e.g. including `li` or `a` elements in your example)?

Comment: `$(this).type` is undefined, you should be using `this.type`.

Comment: James, I would like to get all form related elements like label, input,textarea,radio etc. Preferably in the order they are in the form

Comment: Paul, you are absolutely correct. It works with this.type Labels do not showup though, any idea how to get them?

Comment: @truthSeekr I updated my answer. It now returns the type proprty if it can find it, otherwise the nodeName. It selects all `input`, `textarea`, and `label` elements. If you want to add more than just add more to the `find()` call at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).type` is undefined, you should be using `this.type` to access the type property. You don't really need to use `map()` either to get the elements. You can use this instead:

```
var $test = $($newform.get(0).elements);
```

But since elements won't include `labels` you should just select the elements you want with a selector. Also since `<label>`'s don't have a type property you can access their nodeName instead which will be `label`.

```
var $test= $('#newform').find('input,label,textarea');

if ($test.length != 0) {
    $test.each(function(){
        var type = this.type ? this.type : this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        console.log(type);
    });
}
```

Comment: Labels don't have a type property so you need to make a couple changes for that situation. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Try `this.nodeName` and `$(this).attr('type')` (or this.type):

```
test = $('#newform').map(function(){ return $.makeArray(this.elements); });

if (test.length != 0) {
    test.each(function(){
        if(this.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
            console.log($(this).attr('type'));
        } else {
            console.log(this.nodeName.toLowerCase());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply grab all the form elements?

```
$('#myForm').find('input,textarea')
```

That should grab all input tags and textarea tags.

If you need more tags, simply comma delimit more tag names.

```
$('#myForm').find(('input,textarea,li'); // etc
```

Comment: Is the order in which they appear preserved? I will have to try it out

Comment: I couldn't tell you on that one, but it will select all the elements.

Comment: It does preserve order they appear in the form. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1) as @Tejs points, you can use $('input,textarea')

2) to get the `type` *attribute* use

```
$(this).attr('type')
```